# `kubectl proxy` in pod works, but what credentials is it using?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm playing around with Kubernetes and this time I started a basic pod, `exec`-ed into it, downloaded `kubectl` and executed `kubectl proxy` (exactly like this). To my surprise, I can actually use the API by sending requests to the proxy like `curl localhost:8001/api` and get a response. I had assigned a role to the default service account which allows bearers of its tokens to do stuff as well, and all of this works in the pod as well, just like that.

How does `kubectl proxy` know where my server is at to proxy it, and which credentials to use? I suspect it is using the default service account that is mounted in the projected volume. At the same time, on my local machine, I think it is using the `~/.kube/config` file and the current context. Does it mean that if I disable mounting of the default service account in the pod, but copy my `~/.kube/config` into the pod, `kubectl proxy` could still work (with different credentials, of course, and assuming the pods can reach the host)?

I would be interested in learning what `kubectl` actually uses and what the precedence is (e.g. it first tries to use the `~/.kube/config` file, then tries the well-known paths to see if the service account is mounted, then something else) - and I'm failing at finding such a resource.

My question is: could anybody provide a link where it is described exactly what and in which precedence `kubectl` uses for its credentials source?

EDIT: It seems like `~/.kube/config` has precedence: if it exists in the right place, it is used; otherwise the mounted service account is used.

What is strange is that if there is either `~/.kube/config` or the default service account is mounted, `kubectl proxy` knows the server address, presumably by using the envs (`KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` and `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS`?), but if neither is evailable, `proxy` doesn't even use these vars and tries to proxy `localhost:8080`.

Comment: What is your exact question here ? because it seems like you found your explanation.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear that my question is unclear ;d I edited it to state what I'm after very explicitly - a link where it is described what kubectl uses and in which sequence.